# Не удается периодически подключиться по RDP к windows-server-2008-r2

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-server-2008-r2

Из 30 попыток - только 1 успешная выходит. Остальные с ошибкой.
Включение и отключение брандмауэра не влияет на ситуацию.
Через LiteManager подключаюсь с первого раза. Но он дико неудобен. В чем проблема может быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Порт открыт? Через локального админа пускает?

Comment: @don-rumata Да. После переустановки системы на пару дней все норм становится, потом опять проблема появляется.

Comment: В журналах какие записи сразу после того как тебя посылают?

Comment: @don-rumata Где логи эти посмотреть?

Comment: "В просмотре событий". Там винда хранит всё чё происходит с сервисами.

Comment: В "Event Viewer" / "Remote Desktop Services" записи не создаются о неудачных попытках почему то.

Comment: А об удачных, когда ты через LiteManager цепляешься?

Comment: Тоже нет. Там только записи EventID 1012 "Remote session from client name a exceeded the maximum allowed failed logon attempts. The session was forcibly terminated."

Comment: Ммм... отрубить фаерволл как службу - пробовал?